Residue theorem: Choice of contour
after first learning about the Residue-theorem we now apply it in Quantum Field Theory but now I have realised that I have forgotten a lot of important details. I don't understand when the closed curved needs to be chosen on the upper or lower complex plane. An example would be the integral: $$\int _C \frac{e^{itz}}{z^2+i}dz $$
Now the contour for $t>0$ is chosen such that the singularity in the upper complex plane contributes. For $t<0$ it would be the lower complex plane. I don't see why we can't make the choice of the counter going through the lower complex plane for $t>0$.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Are you trying to choose a contour with the goal of thereby computing $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{itx}\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+i}$ for arbitrary $t\in\Bbb R$, or do you want to do something different?

@J.G. Hi thanks. It's not for arbitrary t but rather for $t>0$ and why the contour has to be chosen such that the upper complex-plane is included.

But you want to evaluate the integral I mentioned, right? If so, it's so the arc's contribution vanishes in the infinite-radius limit by the maximum modulus principle.

Ahh now it makes sense. Thanks a lot! But it only vanishes, if the arc is chosen in the upper half, right?

That's true if $t>0$, yes. If $t<0$ we need the arc in the lower half, which makes the contour clockwise. (You can handle $t=0$ with either, or by continuity.)

I encourage you to take a look at the following proof of Jordan's lemma
As you can see, the requirement for $a$ (or $t$ in your case) to be positive is such that the integral is properly bounded along the arc-part of the semicircle.
